# IBM Watson Assistant: How to retrieve input value from chosen dialog option?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I already followed [these great instructions](https://medium.com/ibm-watson/how-to-dynamically-add-response-options-to-dialog-nodes-in-watson-assistant-e14c5e08beca) on how to dynamically create dialog node options from generic input and it's working like charm. But for now I cannot see how to hand over the chosen option value to the next node to process further. Is there any documentation how to pass the chosen option value to the child node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store any selected option and other information in [context variables](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-runtime-context#dialog-runtime-context-variables). They are passed around and can be accessed in other nodes. The information is available until you unset or delete the context variable.